# flutter_launcher_icons not working with XCode - Flutter

Tags: flutter, xcode, icons

I am using [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) to generate an icon for my flutter project.

I save a PNG image to my assets folder.

[image: folder]

This is my pubspec.yaml

```
flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/ios_icon.png"
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21
```

I then run (which is successful).

```
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons
```

However, when I check Xcode I need to manually drag the icons on the bottom to their respective sizes, which is quite annoying, especially if I just want to make small updates to the icon.

I thought this was all taken care of with the package so wondering what the issue may be.

[image: xcode]

I have run flutter clean and re-run, but doesn't seem to work.